# Getting a specific value from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

i have a multi dimensional array that looks like this:

```
array(54) { 
    [0]=> array(2) 
    { 
        [0]=> string(10) "2017-03-20" 
        [1]=> string(4) "C1.3" 
    }
    [1]=> array(2) 
    { 
        [0]=> string(10) "2017-03-20" 
        [1]=> string(4) "C1.4" 
    }
}
```

And i have got this code to get the results out of it:

```
  $keys = array_keys($EndArray);

  //var_dump($EndArray);
  print("<select>");
  $teller = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($EndArray); $i++) {
      foreach($EndArray[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
      if($teller == 2) {
        $teller = 0;
      }
      echo "<option>".$value." ";

      }
      $teller++;
    }
  print("</select>");
}
```

It does work, but not the way i want it to, because it makes a dropdown with a new line for every part of the array, but i want it to be like this:

```
2017-03-10 C1.3 
2017-03-10 C1.4 
2017-03-10 C1.5 
2017-03-11 C1.1
2017-03-11 C1.2 etc.
```

But i do not know how to make this work, can anyone help me?

Comment: Stop using `for`. You're making the whole process harder. You need to use `foreach`

Comment: But how? @Machavity